# How can I insert a textfield when running tests in swift?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, testing

I have this test:

```
func testLogin() throws {
        viewController.email.insertText("email@outlook.com")
        viewController.password.insertText("secret")
        viewController.btnLogin?.sendActions(for: .touchDown)
        XCTAssert(viewController.loggedIn == true)
    }
```

But it gives me this error on the  first line when I try to insert the email

`Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

How can I get this test to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code block looks incomplete...
You can't directly access the UIElements for XCTests.

As a first step need to create application object

`var app = XCUIApplication()`

then you need to launch the app with

`app.launch()`

then access respective UI element with `accessibilityIdentifier` as

`let email = app.textFields["identifier_of_emil_textfield"]`

UI elements needs to have `accessibilityIdentifier` to work with XCTest framework. If you haven't assign this then you can as `emailTxt.accessibilityIdentifier = "identifier_of_emil_textfield"` or directly from `identity inspector` of respective `XIB` element.

and at last you can use `typeText` property to add your text like

`email.typeText("email@outlook.com")`

Comment: How does XCUIApplication know what app he needs to use?

Comment: If you have single application target then you don't need to define/mention that, XCUIApplication will create and map the existing app target against the test target

Comment: I normally didn't work with multiple app target within same project but if you have so then you may try to import the testable target with. `@testable import AppTarget` and follow the above steps.

Comment: @jordyhuijgens Has it solved your problem?